# Get data from URL using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, url

[image]
This is incoming call API URL. so, this URL wont stop loading. this URL keep loading and give data in json format. how to get data from this kind of URL using PHP.

```
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch,[
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://konnectprodstream3.knowlarity.com:8200/update-stream/api-key/konnect'
        ]);

        // grab URL and pass it to the browser
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        echo $response;

        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Do you need all parameter of data or specefic data?

Comment: what have you tried? You get a json response. zo decode it. This is very basic and you can find it online, no?

Comment: Hi @Sathish and welcome to Stackoverflow. please take a while and read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you used the php CURL to http request.

You can use the laravel HTTP client.

You can see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests

Comment: In my opinion this is a comment, not an answer :-). But you are right.